# How can I remove new blank line that pops up after I execute JQuery Ajax in Rails3?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In `index.html.erb`, I made the button that switches from Follow to Un-follow, Follow to Un-follow back and forth when it's pressed.
It's working perfect but when I press the button, it makes another new line at right below of the button that's shown first when the page is loaded.
Why does it? and How can I remove or fix this new line??

Here are images!

image 1. When the page is loaded

[image: When the page is loaded]

image 2. When the button is pressed first time after loaded

[image: when the button is pressed first time]

image 3. When the button is pressed second time after loaded

[image: when the button is pressed second time]

My codes are

follows_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"create.js"}
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action=>"destroy.js"}
  end
end

end
```

views/users/_follow_user.html.erb

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
        <%= button_to("Un-Follow", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), 
        :method => :delete, 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn') %>
    <% else %>
        <%= button_to("Follow", user_follows_path(user.to_param), 
        :remote => true, 
        :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

views/follows/create.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/follows/destroy.js.erb

```
$('.follow_user[data-user-id="<%=@user.id%>"]').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => @user}) %>');
#jQuery
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%- model_class = User.new.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
</div>
  <% @from %>
  <h3>tag cloud</h3>
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, {:action=>'index', :tag=>tag.name}, :class => css_class%>
  <% end %> 


<%= paginate @users %>

<table class="table table-condensed">
  <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>  
      <div class="memberListBox">
        <div class="memberList">
            <p class="name"><span><%= user.user_profile.nickname %></span>(<%= user.user_profile.age %>)</p>
            <p class="size"><%= user.username %></p>
            <p class="img">
            <% if user.user_profile.user_avatar? %>
            <%= image_tag(user.user_profile.user_avatar.url(:thumb),:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% else %>
            <%= image_tag('nophoto.gif',:height => 100, :width => 100, :class => 'img-polaroid' ) %>
            <% end %>
            </p>
            <div class="introduction">
                <%= user.user_profile.introduction %>
            </div>

<% if user_signed_in? && current_user!=user %>          
<div class="follow_user" data-user-id="<%= user.id %>">
  <%= render :partial => "follow_user", :locals => {:user => user} %>
</div>
<% end %>

  <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> ') + 'Message', new_messages_path(user.username), :class => 'btn btn-primary'  %>


                <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> ') + 'Profile', show_user_path(:username => user.username, :breadcrumb => @from), :class => 'btn btn-info' %>              

        </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

html when the page is loaded(image 1)

```
<div class="follow_user" data-user-id="3">
        <form action="/users/3/follows/133" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" /><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Un-Follow" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eVjePZ0ajS3NfXJLDBkELnpNwyt8k1f59FiT8iv/Xb8=" /></div></form>

</div>
```

html when the button is pressed(image 3)

```
<div class="follow_user" data-user-id="3">
        <form action="/users/3/follows/133" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" /><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Un-Follow" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="S92bRkGcbMz/puQvia4m7IOtrTsO2iCThiaHlBaXmJU=" /></div></form>

</div>
```

Comment: In the browser where you see these images, can you just do 'view-source', and see the difference?

Comment: @Nishant Thanks! I added some extra info to the bottom of my question. It looks there's no difference between before press and after

Comment: @Nishant I might have found a hint. If I see html with Fire Fox, that part is highlighted in red and saying Start tag 'div' seen in 'table' I don't know what it means though

Comment: we are not supposed to use div inside of table or something???

Comment: @HUSTEN this might come from css, there is margin set on some element eg. div/

Comment: I found it myself! I was not supposed to use div tag within table.